# How to Use Eval Method

Tags: java, testing, methods

I'm having a problem trying to get evaluating a String.  My evaluation method is correct so I'm not going to share it, but I can't seem to get the method actually get to the point of evaluation.  I've been trying just about everything and it seems like I'm either getting object references, or it want's identifiers, or different types (static vs non-static).

What I want is to know how to get the method eval() to work.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Postfix
{
    String expr;

    public Postfix(String e)
    {
        expr = e;
    }

    public double eval()
    {
        Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<Double>();
        String[] word = expr.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
        {
            double a, b, c;
            switch(word[i])
            {
                case "+":
                    b = stack.pop();
                    a = stack.pop();
                    stack.push(a + b);
                    break;
                default:
                    stack.push(Double.parseDouble(word[i]));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return stack.peek();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your code?, what do you expect it to to, and what does it do instead, precisely? Include the exact and complete error message you get, if any.

Comment: Rephrase the question , not even able to get it what exactly is your problem ?

Comment: you call the method?

Comment: eval() is supposed to work on a string I enter.  It's meant to turn Postfix into Infix but I don't know how to set and evaluate a string.  So what I'm asking is if you were to type main into this class, what would it look like?

Comment: Try `double result = new Postfix("YOUR STRING HERE").eval();`

Comment: eval() is supposed to work on a string I enter.  It's meant to turn Postfix into Infix but I don't know how to set and evaluate a string.  So what I'm asking is if you were to type main into this class, what would it look like?

Something like:
    String expr = " 3 4 + ";
    Postfix j = new Postfix(expr);
    j.eval()

But I get this: Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException (empty String)

Comment: *My evaluation method is correct so I'm not going to share it*: so, it's correct except it throws an exception every time you call it, right? That would be my definition of "incorrect". Post your code, and post the complete stack trace of the exception if you really want help.

Comment: @JBNizet You're right, sorry.

Comment: Just edited the code.  I'm not sure how to post code in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you still didn't post the stack trace of the exception, although that's where your investigation should always start, since it tells what the problem is, and where it occurs. We have the message of the exception, though, and I can guess from the code where it comes from:

> Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException (empty String)

This comes from the following line:

```
stack.push(Double.parseDouble(word[i]));
```

the value passed to `parseDouble()` is supposed to be a string representing a number, but it's not. It's the empty string, as the error message says.

Why that? Using a debugger would find the problem trivially. You pass the following string `" 3 4 + "` to `expr.split("\\s+")`. The result is the following array (as you would also know by printing it using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(word))`):

```
[, 3, 4, +]
```

It thus contains an empty string at the beginning, caused by the extra leading space in your expression.

Replace it by `"3 4 +"`, or call `expr.trim().split("\\s+");` to make sure the string doesn't contain extra leading and trailing white spaces.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.  I had no idea that it wouldn't throw away the first space.

Answer (score 0):

Rule #1:  If your code doesn't work don't do what I did and not paste it.

Answer:  Add .trim() or else your string will be empty then add another .trim() again or else the answer will be 0.0.

```
String[] word = expr.trim().trim().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning for having two calls to `trim()`.  I think you'll find one is enough.

Comment: Huh, it was giving me 0.0 as an answer with one trim but I'll try it again.

Comment: Yep, one trim works fine.